# Cardinality of $\pi_0(\mathbb{R}^n-A)$ and $\pi_0(\mathbb{R}^n-B)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are closed homeomorphic subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then show that $\pi_0(\mathbb{R}^n-A)$ and $\pi_0(\mathbb{R}^n-B)$ have same cardinality.

I tried showing a bijection between them, I got that there is a continous bijection $f : A \to B$, whose inverse is continous. But with this information I cannot relate $\mathbb{R}^n-A$ and $\mathbb{R}^n-B$, and here this is getting troublesome. Here $\pi_{0}(S)$ denotes the path connected components of $S$.

Can anyone help me with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Use Alexander duality for (co)homology groups.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  We have not covered that yet

Comment: Then what did you cover?

Comment: Basics and Van Kampen Theorem in Homotopy, Excision, Mayer Vietoris', Exact Sequences for pairs, triples and other basic things in homology theory.

Comment: It does not seem to me that you are ready to solve the posed problem. You will need some form of Poincare duality (Alexander duality is a consequence).